# Android using JSON to register and get results from web service - PHP

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, nullpointerexception

I made an android application last year, it worked fine, i've been reassigned to develop the application.

But the registration of a user has stopped working. The reason why, I havnt a clue.

Here is my start screen, the activity where the user registers:

```
public class Prompt extends Activity {

    public EditText u, p, e;
    public String username, password, emailadd;
    public Button createClient;
    final Context context = this;
    public TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prompt);
        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields

        u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        createClient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createClient);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
        u.setText("usernametest");
        p.setText("passwordtest");
        e.setText("TEST@gmail.com");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        createClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = u.getText().toString();
                password = p.getText().toString();
                emailadd = e.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username+" "+password+" "+emailadd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //now we have text input, validate them
                if(username.length() < 5 || password.length() < 5 || emailadd.length() < 5){
                    //minimum input for each field is > 5 characters
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Username, password and email must have must than 5 characters");
                }
                else{
                    //if validated correctly upload
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(username, emailadd, password);
                    Log.e("JSON RESULT", "JSON result: " + json);

                    //successfully make the check file and redirect to the homepage
                    try {
                            String FILE_NAME = "filename.txt";
                            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                            try{
                                fos.write(username.getBytes());
                            }catch (IOException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            fos.close();

                            //if all complete, redirect to home page
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Prompt.this, StrategicEnergyActivity.class);
                            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            finish();
                    } 
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my JSON Parser Class to handle the JSON returned from the web service:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        Log.e("TESTTTT", " " + params.get(0) + " " + params.get(1) + " " + params.get(2)  + " " + params.get(3));
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try{
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Here is my User Functions Class, the class that does the data handling/ method calling:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String registerURL = "http://www.website.com/api/index.php?";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        Log.e("Credentials", "Username: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nPassword: " + password);
        //Toast.makeText(getParent(), name+" "+email+" "+password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Here is the code on my web service:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    $tag = "register";

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if($db->isUserExisted($email)){
            // user is already exists - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User Already Exists";
            echo json_encode($response). "User Already Exists";
        } 
        else{       
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);

            if($user){
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response). "User Stored Successfully";
            } 
            else{
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } 
    else{
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
?>
```

> Finally this is the error that is currently being thrown at me, it
>   occurs in the sb.append(line) line in the JSONParser Class:

```
05-21 16:35:46.304: E/Buffer Error(4278): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 16:35:46.308: E/JSON Parser(4278): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-21 16:35:46.308: E/JSON RESULT(4278): JSON result: null
```

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong here? I would really appreciate any help what so ever.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your web services returning response in browser?

Comment: yeah, it echos the json_response to the browser through an api, the same api the android uses and receives the json response via the http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting occurs when you try to parse JSON with nothing in it. For example, you'd see a similar response if your phone was no connected to the internet and you tried to connect to your server. There'd be no data to parse and and so you'd get a `JSONException`.

My guess is that this is related to you're I/O functions not being on a background thread. Based on the code provided you are running your `HttpPost` within the JSONParser class on the main UI thread. This has been disallowed since API 11. As a result you would get no value to parse and throw a `JSONException`.

Try moving this function to an `AsyncTask`. If you execute your `HttpPost` within the task's `doInBackground` method you will remove the error. [Here is a link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to the android docs related to `AsyncTask`. They provide some helpful code examples.

The basic structure of an `AsyncTask` is as follows:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        //stuff to do in background 
        return result;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //stuff that runs on the UI thread using the result of background thread 
     }
 }
```

In this example, taken from the android docs, you can see a number of key parameters. (1) The arguments/return values for the task indicated in < > (2) the `doInBackground` method which, shocker, runs on a background thread (3) the `onPostExecute` method that runs on the UI thread following the completion of the `doInBackground` method. `onPostExecute` takes as an argument the value returned by `doInBackground`. If you notice, the type of that argument corresponds to the third type in < > at the start of the class.

You're going to have to play around with exactly where this fits in your code but the basic idea is that, any I/O function - like your `HttpPost` takes place on the background thread. Any UI updates, like changing the text in a `TextView`, using a `Toast` or moving things on the screen takes place in `onPostExecute`. In other words, download what you need in `doInBackground` and return the result - in your case some JSON/string - to `onPostExecute` where you can notify the user of a change, e.g. that they were successfully registered or not.

**How to pass values to an AsyncTask**

You asked another question in the comment as to how you would pass a `URL` to an `AsyncTask`. The passing of values to an `AsyncTask` occurs with the `execute()` method  used to start the task. An `AsyncTask` because it is its own class requires that you create an instance of the task first

```
DownloadFilesTask t = new DownloadFilesTask();
```

Once you create an instance of the task you use the `execute()` method to start the task. It is there that you pass in the values you want the task to recieve in the `doInBackgroundMethod`.

```
t.execute(myUrl);
```

to pass more tha one value just add them in seperate by commas

```
t.execute(myUrl1, myUrl2, myUrl3);
```

To retrieve the values passed in you access them from within the `doInBackground` method. `AsyncTask` takes as arguments what are called `varargs`. These are basiclly lists of values of a specific type. In your case, they would be URLs. To access them you get the values by index.

```
URL first = urls[0]
```

For examples, refers to the first URL value you passed into the `AsyncTask`. The name you use to retrieve it corresponds to the name after the . . . that you provide as the arguments for the `doInBackground` method. So for example if you passed one URL to the `AsyncTask` and wanted to retrieve it later for your getWhatever method you would just use

```
getWhatever(urls[0]);
```

If there's more than one URL and this is an iteratvie process you could use a for loop or any other method of going through the URLs provided

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i created this last year, maybe the changes 'as you said' are be causing this. I have no knowledge of this AsynceTask or doInBackground, is there any means of getting some code off you or maybe make an edit to my code? (up vote anyway)

Comment: Thanks a lot, been trying to get this sorted for the last couple of days, feels like its been eroding my brain

Comment: Hey Rarw, I just cant get my head around your explanation, i've added the functinos doInBackground to my JSONParser.java file. But what to do next is confusing. How would I pass the parameters of the URL to the doInBackground function?

Comment: I added an explantion of how to get values from the task

Comment: where should I put this DownloadFilesTask method? Within the JSONParser class?

Comment: From what I can see in your code, yes. Place it within your JSONParcer class with all of the HTTP methods (client, post, get, whatever) going in within doInBackground. If you're using this same server transaction multiple times, you should also look into making the DownloadFilesTask its own public class that takes the applicatino context as an argument. This will give you greater flexibility because you wont have to include the same private class in your other activities every time.

Comment: are you available to talk, i've tweeted you